# Remove duplicates based on conditions in rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe containing many duplicate names, below is a reproducible example.
I am trying to clean the dataset by removing rows that have duplicate names AND lowest information.
I have added a column where I calculate ***% of NA*** of cells in each row, in my example I have called it ***%_Scoring***.

Among the duplicate name rows I want to keep the row that have the ***lowest*** ***%_Scoring (% of NA)***
N:B If *%_Scoring* is equal, it does not matter, one of the two rows should still be removed.

```
data_people <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/max9nc9/Temp/main/data_people.csv"
data_people <- read.csv(data_people, sep = ",")
```

In the above data example, I would only keep 2 rows:

- First row is Margarita Pan
- Second row is John Doe where %_Scoring =
  0.56

Comment: right, I edited my post, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice_max` after grouping by 'Name'

```
library(dplyr)
data_people %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = X._Scoring) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Name          Information                    Height X._Scoring
  <chr>         <chr>                           <dbl>      <dbl>
1 John Doe      This is an information           1.88       0.89
2 Margarita Pan This is an information as well   1.47       0.78
```

---

Or if we want to keep the minimum value, then use `slice_min`

```
data_people %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    slice_min(n = 1, order_by = X._Scoring) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Name          Information                    Height X._Scoring
  <chr>         <chr>                           <dbl>      <dbl>
1 John Doe      This is an information          NA          0.56
2 Margarita Pan This is an information as well   1.47       0.78
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
data_people %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    arrange(X._Scoring) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(Name) & min(X._Scoring))
```

Output

```
  Name          Information                    Height X._Scoring
  <chr>         <chr>                           <dbl>      <dbl>
1 John Doe      This is an information          NA          0.56
2 Margarita Pan This is an information as well   1.47       0.78
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `duplicated` + `ave`

```
subset(
  data_people,
  !duplicated(Name) & ave(rowSums(!is.na(data_people)), Name, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))
)
```

gives

```
           Name                    Information Height X._Scoring
1      John Doe         This is an information   1.88       0.89
2 Margarita Pan This is an information as well   1.47       0.78
```